# Modify content using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have an exercise where I have to create a certain amount of pthreads to de-noise an image but I am having issues with my pointers.  Each thread gets the input_image but then all the threads need to be able to write to the same output_image.  Here are the parts that are relevant.

```
struct task{
    int start_row, stop_row, window_size;
    image_matrix input_image;
    image_matrix * output_image; //holds the address of the original output_matrix
};

void* func( void* arg ){
    task* t_arg = ( task* )arg;

    image_matrix& input = t_arg->input_image;

    //image_matrix& output = t_arg->output_image; 
    image_matrix * matrix_address= t_arg->output_image; //<-----

    for(int y = start; y<=stop; y++){
        for(int x=0;x<input.get_n_cols();x++){
            float filtered_value = median_filter_pixel(input, y, x, window_size);
            *matrix_address.set_pixel(y,x,filtered_value); //<------2
        }
    }
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}


    //This is how I set the output_image in main() but I'm pretty sure
    //this is good.  Filtered image is just   
    td[j].output_image = &filtered_image;
```

This give the error below but I don't understand why.  The value pointed to by matrix_address is of type image_matrix so it should have all the attributes of an image_matrix.  I have tried everything that makes sense to me but nothing is working.  Also when I take away the dereference operator from the line marked 2 it gives the same error which also doesn't make sense to me.

```
request for member ‘set_pixel’ in ‘output_address’, which is of pointer
    type ‘image_matrix*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
```

Comment: Pthreads are so pre 2011...

Comment: Honestly, do not even bother with pthreads. The kind of error you are seeing is a clear indication that any idea of thread is beyond your level. Sorry.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that your output_image is gonna get corrupted

Comment: I have to use threads for the exercise haha.  It is my first introduction to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, member access via `.` and function call `()` both bind tighter than pointer dereference via `*`. In other words, the code is parsed as:

```
*((matrix_address.set_pixel)(y, x, filtered_value))
```

Of course, `matrix_address` is a pointer and as such, it has no members to access. You'd need to introduce parentheses:

```
(*matrix_address).set_pixel(y, x, filtered_value)
```

Of course, this would be extremely tedious to write. That's why C++ has a "access pointee's member operator", `->`:

```
matrix_address->set_pixel(y, x, filtered_value)
```

Comment: OMG such a simple fix for a problem I have been stuck on for so long.  It worked and came out uncorrupted.  Thank you.